# React Native staggered render

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

With this code how would I make the render staggered? I want it to render each element one by one rather than just rendering all at once. I've tried setTimeout but don't know how to implement it or whether its even the right way to do it.

```
renderSelected() {
  var temp=[];
  for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    temp.push(this.selected(i))
  }
  return temp;
 }

selected(number) {
  return (<View key={number} style={styles.normal}  >
    <Text>{number}</Text>
  </View>);
}
```

Update based on the answer but it still doesn't work. The code in the answer was too different since this is React Native.

```
  renderLater(i) {
   TimerMixin.setTimeout(() => {
   this.selected(i);
   }, 100);
 }

renderSelected() {
  var temp=[];
  for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    temp.push(this.renderLater(i))
  }
  return temp;
 }

selected(number) {
  return (<View key={number} style={styles.normal}  >
    <Text>{number}</Text>
  </View>);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code, the problem is that you return `temp` which actually contains nothing, since `renderLater` returns nothing.

A solution is to create an element with a state, and depending on the state your render one or more elements. This is similar to the timer element on the [reactjs page](https://facebook.github.io/react/), where the state is updated every second triggering a new rendering. Instead of changing the ticker every second, you can increase a counter and in `renderSelected()` display all the elements up to that counter. There is no `renderLater`, just a `this.setState()` called regularly triggering a new rendering with a different number of elements.

```
var MyClass = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {counter: 0};
  },
  tick: function() {
    if (this.state.counter >= 10) return;
    this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1});
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {this.tick();}, 50);
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  },
  render: function() {
      var temp=[];
      for (var i = 0; i <= 10 && i <= this.state.counter; i++) {
          temp.push(this.selected(i))
      }
      return temp;
  },
  selected: function(number) {
      return (<View key={number} style={styles.normal}  >
         <Text>{number}</Text>
      </View>);
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<MyClass />, mountNode);
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/2vr9wk8k/1/)

You can also instead create all the elements separately from the start with each an empty `render()` function in the beginning and have them display something when enough time is elapsed. For that, you can still use the `x.setState()` function for each separate element to trigger a new rendering. This avoids erasing and redrawing already drawn elements at each tick.

---

**Old answer:**

You can do a global queue for delayed stuff.

```
var queue = [];

/* executes all element that have their delay elapsed */
function readQueue() {
    var now  = (new Date()).getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
        if (queue[i][0] <= now) { 
            queue[i][1]();
        } else {
            if(i != 0) queue = queue.slice(i);
            return;
        }
    }
    queue = [];
}

/* Delay is in milliseconds, callback is the function to render the element */
function addQueue(delay, callback) {
    var absoluteTime = (new Date()).getTime() + delay;
    for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
        if (absoluteTime < queue[i][0]) {
             queue.splice(i, 0, [absoluteTime, callback]);
             return;
        }
    }
    queue.push_back([absoluteTime, callback]);
}

var queueTimer = setInterval(readQueue, 10); //0.01s granularity
```

With that queue, if you want to render something some elements every 50ms later, then you can just do:

```
function renderElementLater(time, index) {
    /* render */
    addQueue(time, function(){ReactDOM.render(selected(index), mountNode);}):
}
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    renderElementLater(50*i, i);
}
```

You can change the granularity (when the queue is read and checked) to something even less than every 10ms for finer control.

Although, I don't see what's the problem with the `setTimeout`. You could just do:

```
function renderElementLater(time, index) {
    /* render */
    setTimeout(function(){ReactDOM.render(selected(index), mountNode);}, time):
}
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    renderElementLater(50*i, i);
}
```

Maybe your problem came that if you want to use the value of a variable that changes in a callback created in a loop, then it needs to be enclosed by another function (like I did by creating the new function `renderElementLater` instead of directly putting function code there).

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, that's a very thorough answer. Although the code is very different to mine since this is react native. I've updated my question using timeout based on your answer but it still doesn't work.

Comment: OK this is better, it was throwing an error with setInterval so I changed it to "this.interval = TimerMixin.setTimeout(() => {this.tick}, 50);" but it still doesn't work, it only renders the first character. Although as far as I can tell from the code it does seem to be only calling the tick function once?

Comment: @Hasen `setInterval` calls the function regularly. If you use `setTimeout` then instead you need to use it again in the `tick` function after increasing the counter. And instead of `clearInterval`, use `cleatTimeout`.

Comment: setInterval throws the error this.state.counter is undefined. Maybe its not compatible with React Native? Even JS settimeout is not recommended for use with RN, that's why I'm using TimerMixin.

Comment: This was just the `this` that wasn't properly set. I edited the `setInterval`, tested (an alternate code: http://pastebin.com/Ycd9L08P) and it worked. When going native using `View` and `Text` as you did instead should do the trick.

Comment: Aha! Yes that works. Perfect, thanks for so much for your help.